# 3D projection - help understanding formula

Tags: visualization

I'm currently in the starting-phase of making a 3D projection in python. The problem I'm having is understanding the variables presented in the following article;
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

[image: Image of the page I'm interested in.]

Can someone please explain what the variable "e" is? I can't figure out how you would represent the display surface, a plane, as a point...?
Thanks in advance.